# ScriptManager error while loading a page

Tags: ajax, scriptmanager

I just put an ASP:scriptmanager within my login page and for the use of a tag cloud. And after login providing uname and pword redirect to home page.

My home page consists of a master page and I put an ASP:scriptmanager within the master file. But when the home page loads, the following error appears:

> "The control with ID
>   'AutoCompleteExtender1' requires a
>   ScriptManager on the page. The
>   ScriptManager must appear before any
>   controls that need it. "

My home page has several controls used with Ajax.

Can any one help me?

Comment: jball  sorry bro if u give me a help it's precious for me 

I am also add a scroptmanager to the Home page and the follwoing error occured "Only one instance of a ScriptManager can be added to the page. "

Answer (score 0):

first thing you should test  wethere you have created an script manager or not 
test it by  viewing the page source in html if there is any entry not speciting the scriptmanger then its seems that your page is not have any scripmanger on the parent page or the child page.

Comment: I am also add a scriptmanager to the child page and the follwoing error occured "Only one instance of a ScriptManager can be added to the page. " therefore we can guess there are 2 scriptmanagers.consists within the child page and  the parent page.